# ES6 reduce to new object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of all days of a year like so:

```
const days = ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03" ...]
```

And I have an object holding planned and completed tasks for specific days:

```
const tasks = {"2019-01-01": {"planned": 3, "completed": 2,}, "2019-01-03": { "planned": 1, "completed": 0 }, "2019-01-10": { "planned": 1, "completed": 1} ... }
```

What I want is a new object that contains for all days information if tasks were planned and completed or not, like so:

```
const tasksNew = {"2019-01-01": {"planned": 3, "completed": 2}, "2019-02-02": {"planned": 0, "completed": 0} ...}
```

I know this somehow works with reduce but I can't help myself at the moment.

Comment: not able to find difference between expected object & current object

Comment: the days array contains all 365 days of a year, the tasks object holds only tasks for specific days. i want an object that holds all 365 days and the planned and completed items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce` on your `days` array. For each day, it an entry is found in your `tasks` object, add this entry to the accumulator, otherwise, return a default entry.

Here is the [MDN doc on Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const days = ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"];
const tasks = {"2019-01-01": {"planned": 3, "completed": 2,}, "2019-01-03": { "planned": 1, "completed": 0 }, "2019-01-10": { "planned": 1, "completed": 1} };

const tasksNew = days.reduce((accum, day) => {
  accum[day] = tasks[day] ? tasks[day] : { planned: 0, completed: 0 };
  return accum;
}, {});

console.log(tasksNew);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const taskNew = days.reduce((acc, day) => {
  if (!tasks[day]) {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [day]: {
        planned: 0,
        completed: 0
      }
    }
  }  
  return {
    ...acc,
    [day]: tasks[day]
  } 
}, {});
```

for details about reduce:  https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your days array creating a new object. For each day, you'll check if there are a tasks for that day and merge them to your result map, if there are no tasks for that day, merge a default empty "indicator":

```js
const days = [
  "2019-01-01", 
  "2019-01-02", 
  "2019-01-03", 
  "2019-01-04",
  "2019-01-07",
  "2019-01-08",
  "2019-01-09",
  "2019-01-10"
]

const DEFAULT = { "planned": 0, "completed": 0 } 

const tasks = {
  "2019-01-01": {"planned": 3, "completed": 2,}, 
  "2019-01-03": { "planned": 1, "completed": 0 }, 
  "2019-01-10": { "planned": 1, "completed": 1 }
}

const result = days.reduce(
  (map, day) =>
    Object.assign({}, map, { [day]: tasks[day] ? tasks[day] : DEFAULT }),
  {}
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to essentially map the `days` array to the keys in the `tasks` object. Here I loop through every day in `days`, check if it is in the `tasks` object. If it is I add the current `day` as the key and its associated object from `tasks` to the `newTasks` object. If the `day` isn't in the object, then I add the default `complete: 0` and `planned: 0` to the appended array:

```js
const days = ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"],
tasks = {
  "2019-01-01": {
    "planned": 3,
    "completed": 2,
  },
  "2019-01-03": {
    "planned": 1,
    "completed": 0
  },
  "2019-01-10": {
    "planned": 1,
    "completed": 1
  }
},

newTasks = days.reduce((acc, day) => 
                   day in tasks ? 
                   {...acc, [day]: tasks[day]} : 
                   {...acc, [day]: {planned: 0, complete: 0}
                 }, {});

console.log(newTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

clone the `tasks`. Store `keys` of `tasks` in a variable. Then loop through `days` check if `keys` doesnot `includes()` `day` add it the the object `newTasks`

```js
const days = ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03"]

const tasks = {"2019-01-01": {"planned": 3, "completed": 2,}, "2019-01-03": { "planned": 1, "completed": 0 }, "2019-01-10": { "planned": 1, "completed": 1}}

const newTasks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tasks));

const keys = Object.keys(tasks);
days.forEach(day => {
  if(!keys.includes(day))
   newTasks[day] = {completed:0,planned:0} 
   }
)
console.log(newTasks)
```

Answer (score 0):

shortest way:

```
{...days.reduce((obj,d)=>({...obj,[d]:{ planned: 0, completed: 0 }}),{}), ...tasks}
```